# Race condition between wait_event and wake_up in Linux kernel

Tags: linux, concurrency, linux-kernel, race-condition

I'm a kernel newbie. I just got this question when reading the source code.

In the implementation of `wait_event()`, the kernel does something like this:

```
...
prepare_to_wait(); /* enqueue current thread to the wait queue */
...
schedule(); /* invoke deactivate_task() inside, which will dequeue current thread from the runqueue */ 
...
```

in the implementation of "wake_up()", the kernel does the follows:

```
...
try_to_wake_up(); /* invoke activate_task() inside, which will enqueue the target thread into the runqueue */
...
```

in a concurrent execution, what if the above functions are invoked in the following order:

```
...
prepare_to_wait(); /* thread A adds itself to the wait queue */
...
try_to_wake_up(); /* thread B wakes up A and enqueues it into the runqueue */
...
schedule(); /* thread A dequeues itself from the runqueue and yields the CPU */
...
```

Thread A is not in either the runqueue or the wait queue. Does that mean we lost thread A? The kernel must have some mechanism to prevent this from happening. Could someone tell me what I missed here? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer in the article, [*Kernel Korner - Sleeping in the Kernel* in Issue 137 of the Linux Journal](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8144) dated Jul 28, 2005 by **Kedar Sovani**.

In a nutshell, this is the **lost wakeup** issue.  The Linux kernel solves it by setting the task state to **TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE**.  This causes calls to `schedule()` to wake immediately, even if someone has called a wake up function prior to the `schedule()` call [as well as the normal during].

Answer (score 0):

One of the mechanisms from kernel is wait_event*() macros. It works in the way as explained in [Kernel Korner - Sleeping in the Kernel](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8144)